# <c:foreach> doesn't seem to work

Tags: jsp, jstl

I've seen all similar questions but I didn't find any working answer to my issue.

Simple jsp file:

```
   <%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
    <% String[] names = {"Jhn", "Kate", "Larry"};
            pageContext.setAttribute("myNames", names);
    %>
    <html>
    <body>

    <c:forEach var="tempName" items="${myNames}">
        <p>${tempName}</p>
    </c:forEach>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Maven dependencies:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

The output of JSP file is

```
${tempName}
```

Though, I expect

```
Jhn 
Kate 
Larry
```

I feel like I am missing something but can't find out what's wrong.

**Edit:**
I'd like to mention that if I create a dynamic web app and do the same things(except maven dependencies, obviously) - it works perfectly but as soon as I create maven project - it stops to work

Comment: try `request.setAttribute("myNames", names);`

Comment: @JackFlamp sadly, nothing changed

Comment: you must have some issue with your libraries..

Comment: @JackFlamp How can I find out what these issues are?
In build path of the project I have every maven dependency needed to make project work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that is absolutely ridiculous.
It began to work and I changed nothing to make it work.

The only things I've done are:

Added to web.xml into web-app tag:

```
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
version="2.4"
```

then **deleted** it

After I **changed**

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

**to**

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" %>
```

and then back **to**

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

Technically, nothing changed. But somehow it began to work. I have no idea what happened.

**Though, in other similar projects it still doesn't work.**

Comment: I do not know why... but adding the header("xmlns=***version="2.4"") to the web-app helps....